3d Model not deattaching/removing when radio button unselect
The problem is that I am rendering a 3d boat model which has different sections in which there are options with multiple select and single select which are dealt with radio and checkboxes. Now issue is when I select a radio option the model accessory is attached to boat model but as I unselect that option the price of that option is deducted but the model is not removed and frequent clicks on the radio option the calculation also starts to become wrong.
The following is the way I tried. My Laravel blade code where the radio and the checkbox structure is set is:
<input
  class="form-check-input cat-item-check"
  name="{{ $value->multi_select == 2 ? 'option[' . $value->type . ']' : 'option[' . $value1->type . ']' }}"
  type="{{ $value->multi_select == 1 ? 'checkbox' : 'radio' }}"
  value="{{ $option->id }}"
  data-typename="{{ $value1->ltitle }}"
  data-type="{{ $value->multi_select == 2 ? $value->type : $value1->type }}"
  data-parent="{{ $option->parent_id }}"
  data-waschecked="{{ $option->is_standard_option == 1 ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
  data-model="{{ asset('storage/' . $option->file) }}"
  data-price="{{ $option->price }}"
  id="collapse-{{ $option->id }}"
  {{ $option->is_standard_option == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>

The script which I am using is:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const modelPath = '{{ asset('storage/' . $modelPath) }}';
    const container = document.getElementById('3d-model');

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 0.1,
            1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 6);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
    renderer.toneMappingExposure = 2;

    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
    directionalLight.position.set(5, 5, 5).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    const directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
    directionalLight2.position.set(-5, -5, -5).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight2);

    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    const dracoLoader = new THREE.DRACOLoader();
    dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.4.1/");

    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

    let baseModel, additionalModels = [];

    function loadModel(path, targetSize = 8, callback) {
        loader.load(path, function(gltf) {
            const model = gltf.scene;
            model.userData.path = path;
            const bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(model);
            const size = new THREE.Vector3();
            bbox.getSize(size);
            const maxDimension = Math.max(size.x, size.y, size.z);
            const scaleFactor = targetSize / maxDimension;
            model.scale.set(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
            bbox.setFromObject(model);
            const center = new THREE.Vector3();
            bbox.getCenter(center);

            model.position.x -= center.x;
            model.position.y -= center.y;
            model.position.z -= center.z;

            callback(model);
        }, undefined, function(error) {
            console.error('Error loading model:', path, error);
        });
    }

    loadModel(modelPath, 8, function(model) {
        baseModel = model;
        scene.add(baseModel);


        function handleCheckboxClick(input) {
            const modelPath = input.dataset.model;
            const isChecked = input.checked;
            toggleAdditionalModel(modelPath, isChecked);
        }

        let previousSelectedRadio = {};

        function handleRadioClick(input) {
            const modelPath = input.dataset.model;
            const radioGroupName = input.name;
            document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${radioGroupName}"]`).forEach(radio => {
            const otherModelPath = radio.dataset.model;
            const modelIndex = additionalModels.findIndex(m => m.userData.path === otherModelPath);
            if (modelIndex !== -1) {
                scene.remove(additionalModels[modelIndex]);
                additionalModels.splice(modelIndex, 1);
            }
        });

        if (input.checked) {
            toggleAdditionalModel(modelPath, true);
            previousSelectedRadio[radioGroupName] = input;
        }
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('.cat-item-check').forEach(input => {
        if (input.type === 'checkbox') {
            handleCheckboxClick(input);
        } else if (input.type === 'radio') {
            handleRadioClick(input);
        }
        input.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (this.type === 'checkbox') {
                handleCheckboxClick(this);
            } else if (this.type === 'radio') {
                handleRadioClick(this);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function toggleAdditionalModel(path, add) {
            if (add) {
                loadModel(path, 4, function(model) {
                    additionalModels.push(model);
                    if (baseModel) {
                        model.position.copy(baseModel.position);
                        model.scale.copy(baseModel.scale);
                    }
                    scene.add(model);
                });
            } else {
                const modelIndex = additionalModels.findIndex(m => m.userData.path === path);
                if (modelIndex !== -1) {
                    scene.remove(additionalModels[modelIndex]);
                    additionalModels.splice(modelIndex, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.enableDamping = false;
        controls.minDistance = 3;
        controls.maxDistance = 13;

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            controls.update();
        }

        animate();

        // Color picker setup
        const colorPickers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color-picker="true"]');

        colorPickers.forEach(pickerElement => {
            const pickr = Pickr.create({
                el: pickerElement,
                theme: 'classic',
                swatches: [
                    'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
                    'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
                    'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
                    'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
                    'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
                    'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
                    'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
                    'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
                    'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
                    'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
                    'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
                    'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
                ],
                components: {
                    preview: true,
                    opacity: true,
                    hue: true,
                    interaction: {
                        hex: true,
                        rgba: true,
                        input: true,
                        clear: true,
                        save: true
                    }
                }
            });

            pickr.on('save', (color, instance) => {
                const colorOptionId = pickerElement.getAttribute('data-color-option-id');
                const colorType = pickerElement.getAttribute('data-color-option-type');
                const colorPrice = parseFloat(pickerElement.getAttribute('data-color-price'));

                if (colorOptionId && colorType) {
                    const colorSelected = color.toHEXA().toString();
                    const inputName = `option[${colorType}]`;
                    const inputElement = document.querySelector(`input[name="${inputName}"]`);

                    if (inputElement) {
                        inputElement.value = `${colorOptionId}-${colorSelected}`;
                        updateTotalPrice(colorPrice); // Update total price function

                        const firstWord = colorType.split('-')[
                        0]; // Extract "top" from "top-color"

                        let colorApplied = false;

                        additionalModels.forEach(model => {
                            const modelLabel = model.userData.path.toLowerCase();
                            if (modelLabel.includes(firstWord)) {
                                console.log(`Applying color ${colorSelected} to model at path: ${model.userData.path}`);
                                // Apply color to model's material or texture
                                // Example assuming model has a material with a 'color' property
                                model.traverse(child => {
                                    if (child.isMesh) {
                                        child.material.color.set(colorSelected);
                                    }
                                });
                                colorApplied = true;
                            }
                        });

                        if (!colorApplied && baseModel) {
                            let basePartFound = false;
                            baseModel.traverse(child => {
                                if (child.name) {
                                    console.log(
                                        `Checking base model part: '${child.name}' for match with '${firstWord}'`
                                        );


                                    const childName = child.name.trim().toLowerCase();
                                    const checkName = firstWord.trim().toLowerCase();

                                    if (childName === checkName) {
                                        console.log(
                                            `Applying color ${colorSelected} to base model part: ${child.name}`
                                            );
                                        child.traverse(child => {
                                            if (child.isMesh) {
                                                if (child.material) {
                                                    child.material.color.set(
                                                        colorSelected);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                        basePartFound = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            });



                            if (!basePartFound) {
                                console.log(
                                    `No matching part found in additional models or base model for: ${firstWord}`
                                    );
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        console.error(`Input element with name ${inputName} not found.`);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error('Color option ID or type not found.');
                }
            });

        });

        function updateTotalPrice(colorPrice) {
            let totalPrice = parseFloat($('input[name="total_price"]').val());
            totalPrice += parseFloat(colorPrice);

            const currency = "<?php echo get_application_currency()['symbol']; ?>";
            const vatPrice = (totalPrice * 5) / 100;
            const vatTotal = totalPrice + vatPrice;

            $('.sub-total').text(totalPrice.toLocaleString('en-US') + currency);
            $('.vat-price').text(vatPrice.toLocaleString('en-US') + currency);
            $('.vat-total').text(vatTotal.toLocaleString('en-US') + currency);
            $('input[name="total_price"]').val(totalPrice);
        }
    });

So how to fix the issue?
